# Is it possible to use arules package with MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, r, apriori, arules

I have a local MySQL database too big to fit in memory. I need to use the `apriori()` function with some tables.

From the arules documentation I don't see how this can be done.

```
apriori(data, parameter = NULL, appearance = NULL, control = NULL)
```

`data` object of class transactions or any data structure which can be coerced into transactions (e.g., a binary matrix or data.frame).

I've found a [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ibmdbR/index.html) that does exactly what I want but It is for IBM DB2, not MySQL.

Anyone knows how/if this can be done? Thanks.

Edit: There is no way to do this with arules and, as far as I know, no way to do this in R. I've found [this demo](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221019378_MySQL_Data_Mining_Extending_MySQL_to_Support_Data_Mining_Primitives_Demo) to use the apriori algorithm in a MySQL database but unfortunately it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use database with the apriori implementation in arules. You need to select the data you want into a `data.frame` that hopefully fits into memory, and then convert the `data.frame` into a `transactions` object. You could use a sample if it does not fit into memory.

Comment: That's what i thought, thanks :D I found [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221019378_MySQL_Data_Mining_Extending_MySQL_to_Support_Data_Mining_Primitives_Demo](this paper) to apply apriori to MySQL but unfortunately it doesn't work anymore (the paper is from 2010).